# Two and more styled arguments in console log

Tags: javascript, logging, console.log

I can apply multiple styles for single string log entry:

```
console.log('%ctext 1 %ctext 2', 'color: red', 'color: green');
```

I can pass an additional entry to the console log via

```
console.log('%ctext 1 %ctext 2', 'color: red', 'color: green', 'text 3');
```

My goal is to be able to colorize that last additive in situation when I can't append it to the first log argument. So `'%ctext 1 %ctext 2 %ctext 3'` is not an option. I don't know how many texts/styles arguments will be passed to the logger, which logic looks like

```
    args = [...args, additive];
    console.log.apply(this, args);
```

The initial arguments come from the different places of the App, so the first element of the initial args is not the last string entry, and the last element of initial args could be any (string, style-string, object). I tried following approach

```
console.log('%ctext 1 %ctext 2', 'color: red', 'color: green', '%ctext 3', 'color: blue');
```

But it results in "text1 text2 %ctext3 color: blue". How can I apply some style to the last string argument of `console.log` method call in case when length and content of its argument list could be any?

Comment: Where does the style come from for the additive argument?

Comment: Will the additive always be a string? You can use format operators like `%s` in the first string to format an argument as a string.

Comment: e.g. `console.log("%c%s %c%s %c%s", 'color: red', 'text 1', 'color: green', 'text 2', 'color: blue', 'text 3')`

Comment: The `%` operators can only be used in the first argument.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-write#string_substitution_and_formatting)